# transaction failed due to running out of gas. Can I recoup this money?

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, out-of-gas, jaxx

My transaction failed due to running out of gas. Can I recoup this money?

I was trying to send to my Bittrex wallet via my Jaxx wallet. Below is the transaction id. Could someone please help me out, as i am clueless as to what to do.

TxHash:

`0xe03302a5aeb552e97bb93dd05857b50f8741fa1bc0c478c556c9c7766d1978e7`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction failed, then no ether was transferred. You can't recover what you spent on gas (~$0.03), but nothing happened to the rest of the ether.

If Jaxx thinks the ether is gone, then that's a bug in Jaxx. As you can see, your balance is still ~13 ETH: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7d22b18d2a9f97a2d20bfcc079acd9c18bf93fa4.